# Fetching JSONP with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

```
<html ng-app="movieApp">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  var service = '/movie/862';
  var apiKey = '####';
  var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK';
  var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + '&callback=' + callback;
  var movieApp = angular.module('movieApp', []);

  movieApp.controller('MovieCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
      $http.jsonp(url).then(function(data) {
      $scope.movies = data;
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body style="padding:12px;" ng-controller="MovieCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    <h1>{{movie.title}} {{movie.id}}</h1>
    <p>{{movie.overview}}</p>
    <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500{{movie.poster_path}}" style='width:200px'/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to fetch JSON with Angular.js. The information is coming across fine but statuses I believe is also coming across. Resulting in 5 images being placed on the screen, 4 broken and 1 good image along with the data. How can I avoid sending this extra data?

Comment: can you should us your server side ? `/movie/` controller on the back-end specificall just needs to send the required info, you could look into micro services also ..

Comment: What do microservices have to do with anything?

Comment: @DaveNewton nothing specifically but easier to tailor response data. Nothing special though. Just sprung to mind. From my understanding of the question the OP did not want ALL the information from the request, just specific info: reducing the receiving data.

Comment: The API is the API. The code should deal directly with the actual data coming back; adding an additional layer to befunge what the documented API is supposed to do is certainly *possible*, but the biggest ROI would be to just use it in the way it's intended, as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting JSON data with AJAX

You wish to fetch JSON data via AJAX request and render it.
Implement a controller using the $http service to fetch the data and store it in the scope.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <li>{{post.title}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/posts.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.posts = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
});
```

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/requesting-json-data-with-ajax.html

Comment: How does this reduce the bloated data being received ?

Comment: Don't think this is my solution, $http.get doesn't seem work for this scenario. I've tried a couple of examples with get and jsonp seems to be only solution that gave me any success.